# Is there another user authentication gem that doesn't depend on bcrypt?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems, bcrypt

I've been having a hard time with bcrypt and devise and it's messing my whole website up. Is there any other gem like devise which doesn't depend on bcrypt? Or is there another gem such as bcrypt that's compatible with devise?

Thanks.

Comment: Asking for recommendations is off-topic. Why don't you ask for help with bcrypt / devise instead? What do you mean by _"messing my whole website up"_? Can you give some details?

Comment: "messing my whole website up" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also make sure to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

Devise allows you to hook up any encryptor/hasher of your choice: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/how-to:-create-a-custom-encryptor

You could even write your own if you wanted (don't do that).

But if I were you, I'd really try to fix whatever problems you have with bcrypt. It is the industry standard for hashing passwords (at least in rails land).

Comment: I upvoted strictly for **don't do that**

Comment: @engineersmnky: the rest of the answer is also pretty good. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯